# Caching variables in function with Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have two cells. In the first one I set a variable and call a function,  and the second one contains the function definition which makes use of this variable.

When I refresh first cell, the output is always the same despite the value of variable changing. Only when I rerun the cell with the function definition does the output changes

```
In[]:  window=241
       window_t=count_frame_indeces2()
       window_t

Out[]: 241

In[]:  def count_frame_indeces2(window_f=window):
           return window_f
```

Even if I change `window` to 22, output after rerunning this cell the output is still 241. How to avoid caching variable in this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default parameters of the functions get evaluated only at function definition time. So, when you run your second cell, `window_f` gets its default value from the current value of `window`.

When you ran your second cell for the first time, the value of `window` was apparently 241, so that's what the default value of `window_f` became.

Then, you change the value of `window` and call the function without parameter, so the default value (241) gets used.

When you ran the second cell a second time, you defined the function again, and it got the new value of `window` for its default parameter.

Either pass the parameter:

```
window_t=count_frame_indeces2(window)
```

Or make the function use the current value of `window` if no parameter was passed with:

```
def count_frame_indeces2(window_f=None):
    if window_f is None:
        window_f = window

    return window_f
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense to me right now although I would like to reload default value every time the function is called. I found also another solution which resolves my concern. I pasted below.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using `Facade pattern`. I know it's redundant but I don't want to change definition of original function.

```
def count_frame_indeces2(window_f=window):
    return window_f

def count_frame():
    return count_frame_indeces2(window)
```